# Select json multi-layer data in php

Tags: php, json, web

My json file like:

```
{"c_d0_source": "AS-IISNRL",
 "num_of_records": 4921, 
"source": "last-all-airbox by IIS-NRL",
 "version": "2020-05-10T17:01:36Z", 
"descriptions": {"URL": "https://pm25.lass-net.org/data/description.json", 
"c_d0_method": "method/days/distance(km)",
 "c_d0": "calibration PM2.5 (ug/m3)"},
 "feeds": [{"c_d0_method": "BRR/14/10.74", 
"gps_lat": 24.37755,
 "gps_num": 9.0, "s_d1": 0.0},
, {"c_d0_method": "BRR/14/10.74", 
"gps_lat": 24.34755,
 "gps_num": 9.0, "s_d1": 0.0}]}
```

I want to get all the information of "feeds" in "descriptions".

This is my php, and 
my information is from api :

```
  <?php
$fp = gzopen("https://pm25.lass-net.org/data/last-all-airbox.json.gz", "r");
if ($fp){
    $data = array();
    $arr =" ";
    $lines = gzfile('https://pm25.lass-net.org/data/last-all-airbox.json.gz');
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $arr = $arr.$line;   
}
$obj = json_decode($arr);
echo $obj->{"descriptions"}->{"feeds"};
}
else {
    echo ("fail");
}

?>
```

The output is :
Undefined property: stdClass::$feeds .

How can I get this data?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid. When you fix the double comma issue, you'll notice that your "feeds" property is not inside the "description" property. It's on the same level, so use `$obj->feeds` directly.

Try to use "JSON formatter" to detect the problem next time.